# 2010 - Successfully deployed, solution not deployed

Tags: deployment

I am working with a three server farm, 1 CA + service app + WFE, 1 WFE, 1 SQL server. This has been running fine for a long time but suddenly I find myself unable to deploy solutions.

To clarify 'unable to deploy'. The Install-SPSolution command & via UI there are no errors & reports successful but the status remains "not deployed". Same issue captured in image below

I have already tried the first half of [this](http://blogs.technet.com/b/manjesh/archive/2009/10/13/solution-package-gets-deployed-successfully-but-status-shows-not-deployed.aspx) didn't want to remove/readd severs for the second

I have confirmed the service account can still login to SQL manager & has db_owner on the database

UPDATE :  I am able to deploy solutions but it only works one sever at a time

```
 Install-SPSolution "identity.wsp" -GACDeployment
 Install-SPSolution  "identity.wsp" -GACDeployment -local
```

The first command will place the assembly on my WFE   & appear as 'not deployed'. The second commands puts it on my application server & I finally see deployed. I how do I get my system back to deploying both at once ?

Comment: are you login with service account? also make sure this account have permission on COnfig db as well as content database. Also make sure SharePoint admin timer service running on all servers.

Comment: Yes it is running as service account & the accounts have access to the config database. Both services are running on each machine. It appears to deploy successfully on the WFE but does not deploy to the machine it is run on. I do not understand why

Comment: did that server having the internet connection? also try to reboot the server.

Comment: Server has been rebooted, I have come to the conclusion the issue is an incorrect network policy was applied. Will confirm when resolved